# File Put Error while consuming API Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am facing issues, while consuming API in Laravel. Below is error:

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_contents(/var/www/html/trazoo/storage/framework/cache/data/cb/f4/cbf4899d461098a11f02d3b4c1bdbcf7d6c3a5d5): failed to open stream: No such file or directory', '/var/www/html/trazoo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', 122, array('path' => '/var/www/html/trazoo/storage/framework/cache/data/cb/f4/cbf4899d461098a11f02d3b4c1bdbcf7d6c3a5d5', 'contents' => '1578913060i:0;', 'lock' => true))
>   at file_put_contents('/var/www/html/trazoo/storage/framework/cache/data/cb/f4/cbf4899d461098a11f02d3b4c1bdbcf7d6c3a5d5', '1578913060i:0;', 2)
>   in Filesystem.php line 122
>   at Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/trazoo/storage/framework/cache/data/cb/f4/cbf4899d461098a11f02d3b4c1bdbcf7d6c3a5d5', '1578913060i:0;', true)
>   in FileStore.php line 66

But there are lots of folders inside cache/data .. but not this "f4".

Also in FileSystem.php

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
{
    return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
}
```

Dont know what this LOCK_EX means. Is this creating any issue, i have no idea.

So can any one please suggest, where is the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The folder might not be writeable, check for permissions on the cache folder. File put contents may create the file and will need permission to do that.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

from doc: If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

also helpful : [How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Comment: Permission is okay, and there are folders also created every day... but dont know why while specific api this error is coming.

Comment: just an unrelated suggestion, this error happens while handling an exception, I think there is an exception somewhere else and you should be focusing on that. Is this the whole error message ?